# Вставить HTML-шаблон в веб-страницу используя расширение Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Я делаю расширение, в котором нажимая на его иконку, на странице появляется сайдбар (на скриншоте). Сейчас это сделано в background-scripts. Но у меня есть проблемы с отладкой, и я хочу переписать это всё как отдельный шаблон HTML с собственными стилями и скриптами. Вопрос, как вставить такой шаблон в веб-страницу, используя расширение Chrome, чтобы остался доступ к DOM оригинальной страницы?

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "TestAppExtension",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test App"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["app/background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: предназначение background.js в другом, для создания своего шаблона, создайте popup.html и подключите отдельные свои файлы с стилями  JS

Comment: @Arsen мне как раз и не нужен popup.html, потому что у него слишком много ограничений в плане стилей. Нужно чтобы контент страницы сужался влево на 20% и эти 20% занимал сайдбар, как на скрине. Просто сейчас этот сайдбар надо переделать чтобы он подключался как отдельный html-файл к странице на которой было запущено расширение и чтобы он получал доступ к её DOM.

Comment: Popup.html это как пример, вы можете создать любой html файл в котором вставите вашу вёрстку и стили, после через JS вставите содержимое данного html в DOM страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запихайте HTML-шаблон в popup.html или options.html, или в любую другую страницу, подключенную к расширению. Потом возьмите содержимое шаблона (да хоть document.children[0].innerHTML, если нужно вместе с ) и воткните скриптом в сайдбар. На ограничения в плане стилей вам при этом будет абсолютно наплевать, т.к. все элементы будут уже не в popup.html, а в вашем сайдбаре.